# Access and change characteristics of a single line within pandas plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, dataframe

Using the built-in functionality of pandas dataframes to plot, e.g. an unstacked area graph as follows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(11, 3)+3, columns=['r', 'g', 'b'])
df.plot(kind='area', stacked=False, alpha=0.75)
```

Yielding something like this:

[image]

How does one ex-post change the style of only one individual line, changing e.g. its color, linewidth and opacity level etc.?

Answer (score 6):

As noted by @StefanJansen, you can edit a lines' `color` by accessing the `lines` from the given `Axes`.

You can also modify other attributes like so:

```
ax.lines[0].set_linewidth(2)         # set linewidth to 2
ax.lines[0].set_linestyle('dashed')  # other options: 'solid', 'dashdot` or `dotted`
ax.lines[0].set_alpha(0.5)           # Change the transparency
ax.lines[0].set_marker('o')          # Add a circle marker at each data point
ax.lines[0].set_markersize(2)        # change the marker size. an alias is set_ms()
ax.lines[0].set_markerfacecolor      # or set_mfc()
ax.lines[0].set_markeredgecolor      # or set_mec()
```

To change the area under the curve, you want to access the `collections` stored in the `Axes`. Useful attributes here are `color` and `alpha`:

```
ax.collections[0].set_color('yellow')
ax.collections[0].set_alpha(0.3)
```

Obviously, you can change the index `0` in these examples to modify the other `lines`/`collections`.

Comment: wonderful, thanks for this answer @tom. very helpful. 
adding the following code did all the tricks:
ax = df.plot(kind='area', stacked=False)
ax.lines[0].set_color('yellow')
ax.collections[0].set_color('yellow'), however when I want to update the legend with ax.legend(), it appears differently now as if all the lines were only lines and not areas. any hint on that?

Answer (score 2):

If you capture the `axes` returned by `pandas.plot()` like so:

```
ax = df.plot(kind='area', stacked=False, alpha=0.75)
```

Then you can access attributes like `lines` and set parameters like `colors` ([`matplotlib` docs on `axis` API](http://matplotlib.org/api/axis_api.html) for detail on available parameters):

```
ax.lines[0].set_color('red')
```

For your expanded question, the area can be modified through the [collections API](http://matplotlib.org/api/collections_api.html) like so:

```
ax.collections[0].set_color('color_name')
```

Changing the index for `lines` and `collections` allows for updating specific items. As these are iterables, you can also iterate over `lines` or `collections` and do several things:

```
for line in ax.lines:
    line.set_kwarg(foo)
```

Comment: That works great on the lines. Is there are similar way to manipulate the corresponding area under the respective line as well?

Comment: You can also use `fill_between` as demonstrated here: http://telliott99.blogspot.com/2010/02/area-plots-and-filling-in-with.html

Comment: @iMo51: yes, access the `collections` from the `Axes`. See my answer for examples